# Split image by alpha value 1 objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage

[Reference Link here...](http://www.flickr.com/photos/95148356@N02/8719145345/in/photostream)

Please find the image from above link. I need to extract all Black colored sharp objects from the above like specified image to a `NSDictionary`. The goal is to find the sizes of separate objects from split-ted images. I did the image alpha to 1 in object pixels and  other are transparent, say alpha 0. Can anyone help me to achieve it? Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Core image filters [1], or this great post on NSHipster: [2]

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

[2] http://www.nshipster.com/gpuimage/

Comment: Thank you for the valuable links. Actually I need to done it with IOS 4.3 and above. I think, most of the core image library framework controls are available only with IOS 6.0 and later. GPUImage is some what working from SDK 4.0 and later. But still I couldn't able to do my job... :(